# Domains can only be delete or modified by the owner?

Tags: arcmap, esri-geodatabase, domains

Arcmap States that "When a new domain is created, the owner of that domain—that is, the user who created it—is recorded. Only the owner of an attribute domain can delete or modify it."

So say for example a usercreates a domain, then this user leaves the organization. Would it be impossible to then edit or delete that domain?

Comment: You could very easily carry out a test case to prove this yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quote given can be found in the **[ArcGIS 10.1 Help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001s00000005000000)** and goes on to say ...

"This only applies to enterprise geodatabases; in file or personal geodatabases any user can delete or modify a domain. The Domain Properties dialog box lists the owner of each domain when connected to enterprise geodatabases."

In an Enterprise environment I suspect the DBA would be able to ressign ownership from a departing to an alternative (perhaps admin) user.